# Python - Assign a value from one pandas df to another based on a string appearing in text

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example of my data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Text':['This is an example,', 
                'Another sentence is here.', 
                'Lets have fun.', 
                'this happened weeks ago.',
                'I am not sure what to put here.',
                'Another fake sentence.'], 
        'Score':[20, 21, 19, 18, 16, 12]} 
  
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 


data_words = {'words':['is', 
                'fun', 
                'happened', 
                'example'], 
        'frequency':[127, 112, 1234, 32]} 
  
# Create DataFrame 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_words) 



#Final Result:

data_result = {'words':['is', 
                'fun', 
                'happened', 
                'example'], 
        'frequency':[127, 112, 1234, 32],
            'Text': ['This is an example,',
                    'Lets have fun.',
                    'this happened weeks ago.',
                    'This is an example,']} 

df_final = pd.DataFrame(data_result)
```

I am trying to match the `df['text']` with the `df2['words']` based on whether the word appears in the text. I just need one text per word, and ideally it would be based on `"Score"` but it's not completely necessary.

So, the final `df` would have columns: `"Text"`, `"Score"`, `"words"`, and `"frequency"`

Comment: A visualization of the Expected output would be super helpful in understanding the right solution for this.

Comment: @cs95 just added it, didn't see your comment before my first update. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple list comprehension between the two dataframes and take the first occurence with `[0]`

```
df2['Text'] = df2['words'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in df['Text'] if x in y][0])
```

output:

```
    words       frequency   Text
0   is          127         This is an example,
1   fun         112         Lets have fun.
2   happened    1234        this happened weeks ago.
3   example     32          This is an example,
```

Explaining the list comprehension, I am returning the value "y" while searching for "x" in "y" where x is each row for `words` and y is each row for `text`. This returns a list of all matches per row. Some rows had multiple values in the list, since multiple matches, so per your expected output I added a `[0]` to the end in order to take the first value that was returned in each list for the list comprehension that was applied row-by-row with lambda x. Otherwise, without the `[0]`, a list of all matches would be returned.